# How to use a snipmate variable in an expression

Tags: vim, snipmate

How can I use a snipmate variable in an expression?

```
snippet foo
    ${1:4} + 2 = `$1+2`
```

With the default value of 4 the above snippet produces:

```
4 + 2 = 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: which plugin do you use for snipmate ?

Answer (score 0):

At least in the original snipMate plugin, expressions are evaluated first, then tab stops. This allows you to define things like `` ${1:`v:version`} ``, but it makes your use case impossible to achieve.

Have a look at [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715); it is modern and powerful, and might allow this. There are more alternatives, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).